# Permission issue to update LC_ALL in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, permissions

I just installed PostgreSQL following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-14-04) but I'm unable to create a database:

```
createdb test1
```

I get the following error:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "es_VE.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "es_VE.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "es_VE.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "es_VE.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "es_VE.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "es_VE.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "es_VE.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "es_VE.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "es_VE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

This [post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/language-problem-on-ubuntu-14-04) offers the following solution to the issue:

```
export LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"
echo 'LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/default/locale
echo 'LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/default/locale
```

First line is executed without any issue and after that I the language is set to en_US.UTF-8:

```
LANGUAGE = "en_US.UTF-8",
LC_ALL = (unset),
```

LC_ALL is still unset, now with the second line I get a permission  error:

```
 echo 'LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/default/locale
-bash: /etc/default/locale: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not nesesserely have to change it for `/etc/default` - try setting env for your user first:

```
echo 'export LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"' >> ~/.profile
echo 'export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"' >> ~/.profile
```

then log off and log on and run

```
createdb test1
```

Comment: Now I get a different error: createdb: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Comment: I only did this: sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
sudo -i -u postgres     Those are the instructions of the tutorial I followed